# Doctrine/MongoDB mapping Integer always return null

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a mapping problem with mongodb and doctrine.

I have a property called state mapped as an Integer, but when I fetch my object and dump the data, I get the following output :

> object(Me\MyBundle\Document\User)#249 (5) { ["id":protected]=> string(24) "53320c8b03f69d6573a0d510" ["email":protected]=> string(26) "user@gmail.com" ["password":protected]=> string(24) "0251db0188235d115b6caz8t" ["salt":protected]=> string(40) "699fd11d7128344ac8548a8774516338057df384" ["state":"Me\MyBundle\Document\User":private]=> NULL }

As you can see, the state is of type : "Me\MyBundle\Document\User" which is very strange.

When I save a User document, the state property is properly save, but when I fetch a document, state is NULL and wrongly typed.

Here is my entity code.

```
<?php

namespace Me\MyBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="user")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     * @MongoDB\UniqueIndex(name="unique_email", safe=true)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Int
     */
    private $state;
    const STATE_INACTIVE = -1;
    const STATE_NEW = 0;
    const STATE_ACTIVE = 1;
    const STATE_PROMOTED = 2;
}
```

(I omitted getters and setter as the are just as the usual getters/setter generated by doctrine)

Comment: did you try to clear the cache via "app/console ca:c" or "rm -rf app/cache/*", because this sounds like an old hydrator might still be cached.

Comment: Thanks, that was it ! Sometime the most obvious solution is the one you don't think about ...